# Can't install Angular CLI, issue with permissions?

Tags: angular, macos, terminal, npm-install

I can't seem to install the Angular CLI (from [the Angular tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt0)). I'm not very familiar at all with the command line, so please be patient and let me know what information I need to provide.

[Screenshot of the error in the Terminal window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcrSU.png)

I have tried installing as root/Administrator and I just get the same error. I am installing on my personal MacBook Air laptop.

Edit: I have also tried force and sudo installing from the command line, to no avail.

Edit (2): Per a commenter's suggestion, I have tested the versions of node and npm:

- `node -v` results in `v8.11.2`
- `npm -v` results in `5.6.0`
- `npm i -g @angular/cli typescript` results in the following error:

  `npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

Edit (4):

Below is the screenshot after entering the following command in Terminal:

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

[Error after sudo install of @angular/cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edtLo.png)

Edit (5):
Screenshot after entering the following commands:

`sudo chown -R kailynnelson /usr/local/lib/node_modules`

`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`

[Error after sudo chown -R $USER and sudo npm install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQkLv.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Solution 2: *Quote from [docs.npmjs.com](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions)*

To minimize the chance of permissions errors, you can configure npm to use a different directory. In this example, it will be a hidden directory on your home folder.

Back-up your computer before you start.

Make a directory for global installations:

```
 mkdir ~/.npm-global
```

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

```
 npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
```

Open or create a ~/.profile file and add this line:

```
 export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
```

Back on the command line, update your system variables:

```
 source ~/.profile
```

*Quote end.*

Whit this, you will set `npm` and `node_module` directories to your Home directory. You should not have any access problem with global installs of npm modules and you can run them without `sudo`

Comment: Hi @darko99, can you describe what this does please?

Comment: @Krn It transfers ownership of the aforementioned directory to the current user, effectively giving full read, write, delete, etc permissions. That should give you missing writing access and prevent similar future problems with that directory.

Comment: Seems strange that I keep having to add `sudo` before my commands. Why is that? Still no dice after trying your solution; I updated the original post to include a screenshot of the Terminal window (see edit 5).

Comment: @Krn `sudo` is used to elevate your commands to admin level. You need that elevation if command wants to change system files or create under system directories. As a regular user, you don't have access level to modify them. You could disable that but it is a bad idea because you could mess something up with more ease or open doors to potential malevolent applications to wreak havoc on your system.

Comment: Oh, duh, I should have checked their docs better. I tried this and it seems to have worked, although I did still have to use `sudo`. I tried it once without `sudo` and it didn't work. Thank you so much!

Comment: P.S. I had to close out of the application for a few minutes, and when I went to run it again, I couldn't get it to reopen. I followed some suggestions here https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5021 but kbradl16's solution was what helped me.

Answer (score 0):

first you must have the node mounted on your machine, and consequently also the npm
to check if they have installed use `node -v`  `npm -v` on your terminal
then just install the typescript and the angular CLI with `npm i -g @ angular/cli typescript`

after that to check if everything is working correctly use `ng`

check if your user has permission to write to the folder, if you can not, instead of installing global you can do a local installation of angular cli

Comment: @guaracy-a-lima Thanks for the info, but I still get the error. Please see the original question for the versions of node and npm I have installed.

Answer (score -1):

**|||| UPDATED THE ANSWER ||||**

Execute `sudo npm install --global --unsafe-perm` and post the 
output.

**^^^^ UPDATED THE ANSWER ^^^^**

Common practices:

1. Execute `npm` command with prefix `sudo` (`sudo npm install -g @angular/cli`)

What it does it is installing the package as root and root has access to everything.

2. Enter the `root` account. (Highly not recommended due to potential OS breaking issues)

You must execute EVERY command as root.

Executing something directly from root's account is very bad practice and usually unnecessary. Better to use `sudo`, but only in cases when it is really necessary.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Thx for the suggestion, this hasn’t worked either. It still says there is a permission issue, even from root

Comment: Can you post terminal output please? I just installed package it was a success.

Comment: If you receive ```npm WARN``` it is OK, package will work.

Comment: My terminal output is: ```/usr/bin/ng -> /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@6.0.8 postinstall /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/ng-update-message.js

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

+ @angular/cli@6.0.8
added 247 packages from 189 contributors in 17.667s```

Comment: I just added the output in the second image linked in the original post. **Output was too long to paste here in a comment.

Comment: Here is the output: `npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "" as it does not contain a package.json file.`